# nativescript - How to simulate the Back button on a mobile app?

Tags: android, back-button, nativescript

Currently I am working on a mobile application using Nativescript. I would like to simulate the Back button by clicking a component in my UI (when user clicks it it navigates back to previous screen).

```
Scenario:
Page 1 --> Page 2
Page 2 : click on component to go back to Page 1
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in pageB.js

```
var frameModule = require("ui/frame");
var topmost = frameModule.topmost();

function onTap() {
    topmost.goBack();
}

exports.onTap = onTap;
```

in pageB.xml

```
<Button text="BACK" tap="onTap" />
```

More detailed information at the following documentation article:

https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#architecture-and-navigation

Comment: Thank you so much @Nick. This was helpful!